# search between a range based on user input with SQLAlchemy?

Tags: postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

I currently have a a few queries that run fine using one value passed from a form, but now I am attempting to search between a range of numbers that requires passing two values to the query (min and max length) and I can't seem to work it out.

I've tried a few ways of doing this but cannot seem to get it to work as I'm not sure how to make the form pass two values to the query, this is what I'm currently trying:

```
query = query.filter(engorder.extlength.between (f'{value}', f'{value}'))
```

I can see in my console that the sql its using shows

```
 WHERE CAST(engorder.extlength AS VARCHAR) ILIKE %(param_1)s AND engorder.extlength BETWEEN %(extlength_1)s AND %(extlength_2)s ORDER BY engorder.startchass DESC, engorder.startchass DESC
2018-07-10 12:33:48,675 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.base.Engine {'param_1': '10000', 'extlength_1': '10000', 'extlength_2': '10000'}
```

So i can see that is trying to search between two values but I just don't know how to pass them to the query from the form on my template.

I apologise if this is unclear as I'm trying to wrap my head around it all at the moment, if any clarity is needed I'll be happy to try and explain better.

Comment: You're passing the same `value`, interpolated in a string, twice to `between()`. What did you mean instead? Why is this behaviour surprising? You have not shown any code including any forms. You also ask a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51259729/convert-raw-sql-to-sqlalchemy-orm-code) (same table names etc., use of cast + like etc.) as [another user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9035021/keyring88), which is odd.

Comment: We are both attempting to learn flask so that is where the similarity is, i don't see how our questions are similar but I digress. 

I am aware that I am incorrectly passing information to the query (at this point in trying to work it out I've copy pasted the same form field) what I'd like to know is how do I pass a second value to the query, is there a way of instructing my form our wording my query so that formfield1 passes value1 and formfield 2 passes value2 to the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to answer my own question (did some time ago but did not update my question, this is for anyone else having a similar issue.)

```
query = query.filter(engorder.extlength.between(request.form.get('minlength') or '0',request.form.get('maxlength') or '17000')).order_by(engorder.startchass.desc())
```

Turned out it was a quite a simple solution using between and setting limits on the maximum length.